# How can ı sort string and its corresponding integer in c++?

Tags: c++

Hello ı have a string vector (favseries) which includes actornames. and ı created three vector to store the count (vector  counts), store the actors (vector  actors), store the actors provided each actor be once (vector  uniqueactors)  ;ı want to find actorname's counts and display each actornames with their counts with sorted counts high to low, if counts are same, sorted strings from "A" to "Z".

my string vector includes :

```
WENTWORTH MILLER  FREYA ALLAN  YASEN ATOUR  BASIL EIDENBENZ  ANYA CHALOTRA  
BRYAN CRANSTON  RAINN WILSON  WENTWORTH MILLER  LESLIE DAVID BAKER  BRYAN CRANSTON  ANYA CHALOTRA YASEN ATOUR
```

here is the output must be:

```
ANYA CHALOTRA: 2
BRYAN CRANSTON: 2
WENTWORTH MILLER: 2
YASEN ATOUR: 2
BASIL EIDENBENZ: 1
FREYA ALLAN: 1
LESLIE DAVID BAKER: 1
RAINN WILSON: 1
```

my output is error called vector out of range in the sort part. also my output when does not give any error, it prints like no sorted string according to 0'th index and one actor was printed two times with count 1. for example:

```
ANYA CHALOTRA: 1
BRYAN CRANSTON: 1
WENTWORTH MILLER: 1
YASEN ATOUR: 1
BASIL EIDENBENZ: 1
YASEN ATOUR: 1
ANYA CHALOTRA: 1
BRYAN CRANSTON: 1
WENTWORTH MILLER: 1
FREYA ALLAN: 1
LESLIE DAVID BAKER: 1
RAINN WILSON: 1
```

here is the code:

```
    vector <string> actors;
    vector <int> counts;
    vector <string> uniqueactors;
    int count;
    for ( int i = 0; i < favSeries.size(); i++) { 
        for ( int j = 0; j < favSeries[i].actorNames.size(); j++) {
            count = 1;
            counts.push_back(count);
            actors.push_back(favSeries[i].actorNames[j]);
        }
    }
    uniqueactors.push_back(actors[0]);
    for ( int i = 0; i < actors.size(); i++ ) {
        bool check = true;
        for ( int j = 0; j < uniqueactors.size(); j++ ) {
            if ( uniqueactors[j] == actors[i] ) {
                counts[j] += 1;
                check = false;
            }
        }
        if (check) {
            uniqueactors.push_back(actors[i]);
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < uniqueactors.size() - 1; i++) {
    int minindex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < uniqueactors.size(); j++) {
            if  (actors[minindex].at(0) > uniqueactors[j].at(0)) {
                minindex = j; 
            }
        }
        string temp = uniqueactors[i];
        uniqueactors[i] = uniqueactors[minindex];
        uniqueactors[minindex] = temp;
        int temp1 = counts[i];
        counts[i] = counts[minindex];
        counts[minindex] = temp1;
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < counts.size() - 1; i++) {
        int minindex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < counts.size(); j++) {
            if( counts[minindex] > counts[j] ) {
                minindex = j;
            }
        }
        int temp1 = counts[i];
        counts[i] = counts[minindex];
        counts[minindex] = temp1;
        string temp = uniqueactors[i];
        uniqueactors[i] = uniqueactors[minindex];
        uniqueactors[minindex] = temp;
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < uniqueactors.size(); i++ ) {
        cout << uniqueactors[i] << ":" << count << endl;
    }
}
```

or can you rearrange vector and sorting? thank you...

Comment: The simplest answer is to store the actor name and actor count together in a vector of structs. Then when you sort that vector, the actor and their count get sorted together. You're making life hard by storing the actor and the count in separate vectors.

Comment: there is a struct in my class cpp file. ı can not add a new struct to my class cpp file. the code in upper is a part of a class and its a function called printfavouriteactor.

Comment: also yes ı want to sort firstly their occurences then, names 0th index from "A" to "Z".

Comment: please include the homework constraints in the question, you said you can't use `<algorithm>`, and neither `begin()` or `sort()`? Can you use `multiset` and range-based for loops ?

Comment: yes we can use selection sort and swap method for sorting, rest of is about vectors for storing these actornames and their counts. actornames and counts are different vectors. storing actornames another vector, counts corresponding to its names is another vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort()` from `algorithm` in stl.

```
vector<int> v;
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a, int b){
    return a < b;
})
```

Similar to this, you can easily implement this for different arrays.
Read more about [sort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

I would also advise you to use struct or a [`pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/).

Once you store the string and the count in a pair, here is the code:

```
vector<pair<string, int>> v;
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto a, auto b){
    if(a.second > b.second){
        return a.second > b.second;
    } else {
        return a.first > b.first;
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, ı can not use algorithm header, or begin(), sort() functions. it was prohibited. ı need to use only selection sort method for sorting.

Comment: You can still pair them up and try to add appropriate compare condition. It won't be that complicated. Give it a shot.